# Append comma to integer in the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to have comma sepearated ID as i am doing for string like this for ProductCd :
How to do ProductId as it is integer ??

```
PricingProductDetail = new PricingProductDetail
{
    ProductCd = String.Join(",", g.Select(s => s.ProductCd)),
    OpportunityId = String.Join(", ", g.Select(s => s.OpportunityId.Trim())),
    ProductId = String.Join(",", g.Select(s => s.ProducId))
},
```

Thanks.

Comment: if `ProductId` is `int` - you can't assign string to it

Comment: **Short answer:** `g.Select(s => s.ProductId.ToString())`. **Long answer:** Don't, just don't. It's never a good idea to have comma separated ids (unless someone else's awful design forces you).

Comment: @Leri, OP already do this, and `String.Join` available paramrter `IEnumerable<T>` so `ToString` not needed

Comment: @Grundy Well, that's generic overload which won't be called out of the box, atm unless defined manually.

Comment: @Leri, i not understand what you mean, this method was used if argument not string array

Comment: @Grundy Look at what OP is trying to do. He tries to assign comma separated string to integer. :) that's what I meant.

Comment: @Rahul, so, you say that msdn wrong? :-) or what?

Comment: Not sure if a person with 1k sof rep should be asking a question like this? "I can't assign a string to integer field?"

Comment: Please fully explain your actual problem. _"I cannot assign a string to an integer"_ is not answerable. The answer may hint towards a view model, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Integer cannot contains comma separated values.
ProductId should be an array (or list) of int. In this way you can perform the Projection.

```
g.Select(s => s.ProducId)
```